# How to implement server-side multiplayer for a simple JS game?

Tags: javascript, arrays, libraries, multiplayer

Thank you, this is my first post so please correct me on any etiquette. I am a beginner programmer and I want to make a game in JavaScript for one of my classes. Specifically, my Latin class for an "anything" project. My goal is to make somewhat of a Roman-themed version of Among Us. I already have basic movement, and an Apache server running my game. The only thing that I need help with here is making it multiplayer.

The way I want to do this is to have an array on the server where each row is a player, and their username, password, coordinates, and various states (connected, dead, role, etc.) is stored in each column. Only the username, coordinates, and some of the states need to be made available to each client. This is to be copied into an array for each client, who will then take this information and display it.
A client takes control of their character by entering their index and password, at which point a 1D array on the client-side will be created that stores their coordinates, which can be changed by the player using their controls, and sent to the server to be stored in the main array.

I've honestly tried to research this, and I have learned a little bit about databases like MySQL, and server-side languages like PHP and node.js. The problem with these is that, as far as I know, they run once at loading and cannot be manipulated further. 
I don't care about anything like separate lobbies at this point, my class is of only 30.
Does anyone know of any good libraries or tutorials for this? Or is there a better direction to go entirely? I hope to make this mobile-compatible.
If needed, I can provide the URL to my website and the code so far.

Comment: From what I understand perhaps all you need is a nodejs server running a Socket.IO to communicate with your app. Also perhaps you could have a nodejs server with EJS views where you display your current page on '/' , this would make working with sockets easier.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "page on "/" and can EJS interfact node.js with client-side js? Sorry.

Comment: EJS is a rendering engine. You have a node app with several endpoints,for example  when one is called eg. localhost:5000/play it loads the HTML&JS files that you have stored in the appropriate directories like Pages for HTML files (which get converted into .ejs files in this case) and public for CSS,JS,IMG. Then from within the pages you could for starters populate it with EJS variables like current player, status, ecc. Afterwards you could update that through the socket.io connection.

Comment: https://github.com/nikolap994/Socket-io-boilerplate this could be a good starting point.

Comment: Oh I somewhat understand now thank you very much. So the EJS variables will be like JS variables but can be changed externally after the page is loaded?

Comment: the server endpoint would look like this: `res.render('index',{title:"my app"});` and on the client side (ejs file) looks like this `<h1 id='title'><%= title %></h1>`. You can access it through javascript if you assign an id to it. On the other hand, client-side javascript `var socket = io.connect('/');` `socket.on('incoming_data', function (data) {//do something}`

Comment: Thank you very much. I have learned socket.io+node.js sufficiently to implement it into my game.

Answer (score 0):

You want to figure out if you're going to do it in 3D or 2D, pick your language, and implement what you said in said language.

The main thing I think you're missing is the data transport, which can be provided to you with a TCP websocket library like socket.io or socks, which will facilitate an instant, constant data flow between server and client.

The other thing you're missing is a graphics library, which you can do more research on after you figure out whether or not you're doing 2D or 3D.

Comment: I am already doing it in 2d, and the game will run in Javascript, so I am not concerned about a graphics library.

Comment: Thank you for the websocket library recommendation